# Exec format error in execl()

Tags: c++, c, linux, exec, qt-creator

(Sorry for my english)
I'm trying to make simple console application.
I have qtqreator + ubuntu.
I make a pipe, read some info from file into pipe, and my "fork"-process must disply it.
So my code is:

```
using namespace std;
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int fildes[2]; 
    char ch;
    FILE *fp;
    int stat;
    pipe(fildes); 
    cout << argv[1] << " " << argv[2] << endl;
    fp=fopen(argv[1],"r"); 

    if (!fork()) 
    { 
        execl(argv[2],argv[2],&fildes[0],NULL); 
        perror("execl() failure!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while(!feof(fp))
        { 
            ch=fgetc(fp);
            write(fildes[1],&ch,1);
        }

        fclose(fp); 

        wait(&stat); 

        close(fildes[0]); 
        close(fildes[1]);
    }
}
```

The main problem is in `execl()` function: Exec format error.
I've tried different ways to write my path, but nothing works((
Please, help me! Thanks)

Comment: 1. your code *always* shows the "failure" text, regardless of it failing or not. 2. What path? There is none in your code.

Comment: @Jongware - No, if success, execl() doesn't return.

Comment: @codenheim: oops :P That leaves the path notation, then.

Comment: :) @Jongware;  JeSa - Show the command string that you are passing?

Comment: I've tried a lot ))
/home/jesa/p1
/home/jesa/p1.c
/home/jesa/p1.cpp
./p1 (in my dir) and others and others

Comment: If you do `file p1`, what output do you get?

Comment: Exec format error says that "what you are trying to run is not an executable file", basically.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, you mean from terminal? so my program starts, but not successful because I must give it pipe as a parametr, and from terminal I couldn't

Comment: @MatsPetersson, how can I create an executable file with my code?))

Comment: `file` is a command, it describes the file in question. exec is used to _execute_ another program from the first program. Your execl() call must be given a program, not a .c file

Comment: How do you mean? Like `system("g++ myfile.cpp -o myfile");`?

Comment: If I type `file a.out`, I get `a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped`. You should type `file p1` or whatever it is you are trying to executed, and post back the result.

Comment: Oohh my problem is about Linux, I use it for a week, and dont understand a lot

Comment: @MatsPetersson Result: C source,UTF-8 Unicode text

Comment: Well, then you probably want to compile that into an executable file first, same as you have done with the code you have above. In other words `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic somename.c -o somename`

Comment: @MatsPetersson, It doesn't like this because of parametrs of my function

Comment: @MatsPetersson, I've found the solution! Thank You very much)))

Comment: I used next command: g++ p1.c &1 NULL -o p1.c , terminal was angry, but it made an executable file p1 for me